# How to use common code for Sencha UI?

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2

In my application, i have a topbar and bottom tab bar in all the screen. So when user will click a particular tab, it will change only the middle part(the tabbar and toolbar will be same) of the screen. So i want to write some common code for this tabbar and toolbar. So where should i keep those common code?? Is it in view folder??

If any one can share some code or sample project, it will be helpful for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you are going to build an application which is highly optimized.

The best practice is:

1) Your ***MainView.js*** should look like:

```
Ext.define('app.views.MainView', {
  extend: 'Ext.Container' // container is the best way almost time
  config: {
    layout: 'card' // just for example
    items: [
       {xtype: 'MainTopToolbar'},
       {xtype: 'DynamicView'},
       {xtype: 'MainTabBar'},
    ]
    // other configs go here...
  }
})
```

The purpose of this step is to define an overall layout for your application. As you can see, it contains 3 main components (with the second one dynamic - that's where you're going to change according to user's interactions).

2) Define your ***xtypes***, for example, ***MainTabBar***:

```
Ext.define('app.views.MainTabBar', {
  extend: 'Ext.TabBar',
  xtype: 'MainTabBar'.
  config: {
    docked: 'bottom',
    items: [
       // your tabs are defined here, see Ext.TabBar docs for more details
    ]
    // other configs go here...
  }
})
```

3) Put all your xtypes definition file, as well as ***MainView.js*** in **view** folder.

4) In ***app.js***, call `Ext.create('app.views.MainView');`

This problem is quite general and a little bit complicated, so please spend time brainstorming. If there's anything clear, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..Can you help me?? How can i add big icons in sencha tabbar??

Comment: have you posted it as a question yet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366845/how-to-make-bigger-icons-in-bottom-tab-bar-in-sencha